# HTML/CSS (Twitter Bootstrap) footer not displaying properly when using a fixed width container?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my HTML page, I have made a container that contains the entire body (header and footer included). But the problem I am facing is that when I set the container to a fixed width, the header and the left side of the footer display properly, but the right side of the footer extends on indefinitely. Here is my CSS:

```
.container
{
    width: 1024px;
}

.footer
{
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    width:100%;
    background: #0B3B17;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

I think it may have something to do with the absolute positioning, but I need my footer to be absolutely positioned since it keeps moving out of place. What would you suggest? I am using Twitter Bootstrap for development by the way. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `position:relative;` to `.container` rule.

```
.container {
 width: 1024px;
 position: relative;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of the footer is relatively body position.. So will be in the body of the same width.

I think [sticky-footer](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/sticky-footer.html) will be you a better solution.

Comment: The sticky footer is not what I am shooting for in my case. I used the second answer instead. Thanks anyways.